# How to force a Kendo grid update even when no data is updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to upload an image for a product in Kendo grid (inline editing). In insert it's working fine. In update it's not allowing me to change only the image. After I click the update button, it's not going to the controller unless I change one of the other fields.

So if there is a way to force the update button to go to the controller it will be helpful.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("BrandGrid")
                    .Events(e => e.Edit("edit").DataBound("onDataBound").Cancel("onDataBound")) 
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

                .Ajax()
                .ServerOperation(true)
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))


                .PageSize(10)
                   .Model(  model =>{
                       model.Id(p => p.BrandID);
                       model.Field(p => p.BrandID).Editable(false);


                   })

                   .Update(update => update.Action("Brand_Update", "Brands"))
                   .Create(insert => insert.Action("Brand_Insert", "Brands"))
                   .Read(read => read.Action("Brand_Read", "Brands"))
                   .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Brand_Delete", "Brands"))

            )
         .Columns(columns =>
         {
             columns.Bound(p => p.BrandID).Groupable(false).Title(MyResources.LabelBrandID).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:" + MyResources.HeaderDirection });
             columns.Bound(p => p.BrandNameE).Title(MyResources.LabelBrandNameE).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:" + MyResources.HeaderDirection });
             columns.Bound(p => p.BrandNameA).Title(MyResources.LabelBrandNameA).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:" + MyResources.HeaderDirection });
             columns.Bound(p => p.BrandID).Width(120).Title(" ").Filterable(false)
            .ClientTemplate(@"<img alt='Brand Image' src='" + Url.Content("~/Images/Brands/") + "#=data.BrandID#.jpg' alt=\"${data.BrandID}\" />");

             columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title(" ").ClientTemplate("<input type=file name='files' onchange='dataBound(this.value)' />").Width(280).Hidden(true);                 
             columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(MyResources.EditText).CancelText(MyResources.CancelText).UpdateText(MyResources.UpdateText); command.Destroy().Text(MyResources.Delete); });



         })

                             .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text(MyResources.AddNewItem))
                     .Pageable(pager => pager
                    .Numeric(true)
                        .PreviousNext(true)
                        .Refresh(true)
                        .PageSizes(true)
                  )



                             .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                                .Extra(true)
                                .Operators(operators => operators
                                   .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                   .StartsWith(MyResources.StartsWith)
                                   .IsEqualTo(MyResources.IsEqualTo)
                                   .IsNotEqualTo(MyResources.IsNotEqualTo)
                                   .Contains(MyResources.Contains)
                                   .DoesNotContain(MyResources.DoesNotContain)
                                   .EndsWith(MyResources.EndsWith)
                                    )
                                   .ForNumber(num => num.IsEqualTo(MyResources.IsEqualTo).IsGreaterThan(MyResources.IsGreaterThan).IsNotEqualTo(MyResources.IsNotEqualTo).IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(MyResources.IsGreaterThanOrEqualto).IsLessThanOrEqualTo(MyResources.IsLessThanOrEqualTo).IsLessThan(MyResources.IsLessThan))
                                   )

                              .Messages(messages => messages.Info(MyResources.Info).Filter(MyResources.Filter).Clear(MyResources.Clear).And(MyResources.And).Or(MyResources.Or))
                                  )

                           .Pageable(pager => pager.Messages(messages => messages.Display(MyResources.Display).Empty(MyResources.Empty).First(MyResources.GoToTheFirstPage).Last(MyResources.GoToTheLastPage).Next(MyResources.GoToTheNextPage).Previous(MyResources.GoToThePreviousPage).Of(MyResources.of).Page(MyResources.page).ItemsPerPage(MyResources.ItemsPerPage).Refresh(MyResources.Refresh)))


                .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                .Navigatable()
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(405))
                .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                //.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
                                        .Editable(editablee => editablee.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(MyResources.DeleteConfirmMessage))

                )
```

Comment: Share some code so we can see what you are doing, it sounds like the model is not changed for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kendo UI only update records if they are `dirty` which means that some of the fields in the **model** have been modified.

If you do not change the model but directly the data in the array, then KendoUI doesn't know that the record has actually been modified (that's why we have to use `set`, for controlling if `dirty` needs to be switched to `true`).

Not sure how you change *image* I agree with @PeturSubev that maybe would be easier if you share your code because we can see what is wrong.

If this is not possible you can force a dataItem to get `dirty` by doing:

```
// item is the reference to the data in the Grid DataSource
data.dirty = true;
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").saveChanges();
```

Example in here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/pPkWc/